# Issues with enabling pg_stat_statements

Tags: postgresql-performance, postgresql-9.6

I am having issues quering pg_stat_statements and puzzled what else I missed?

See below what I have done. I still have issues when I query pg_stat_statements! I got error saying the libraries is not loaded.

1. #show config_file;

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 /var/opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

2. I have edit the config file and add the following

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'         # (change requires restart)
pg_stat_statements.max = 10000
pg_stat_statements.track = all
```

3.# \dx

```
                                     List of installed extensions
        Name        | Version |   Schema   |                        Description
--------------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 pg_stat_statements | 1.4     | public     | track execution statistics of all SQL statements executed
 plpgsql            | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(2 rows)
```

4. #select count(*) from pg_stat_activity;

```
 count
-------
    43
(1 row)
```

5. #select * from pg_stat_statements;

```
ERROR:  pg_stat_statements must be loaded via shared_preload_libraries
```

Thanks,
Lucia

Comment: Just to be sure: you _did_ restart Postgres after changing `shared_preload_libraries`?

Comment: Yes, I did multiple times actually

Answer (score 0):

In case of such issues it may be useful to check:

1. `show shared_preload_libraries ;`
2. `select name,setting,source,sourcefile,sourceline,pending_restart from pg_settings where name = 'shared_preload_libraries';`
   Maybe something overrides your `shared_preload_libraries` somewhere or maybe server didn't actually restart, then 2. will show that as `setting` field will show something else than `pg_stat_statements` or `pending_restart` will show `t` if that change still waits for restart.

(i don't have comment rights here, so i post as answer hoping it will help)

Comment: Thank you all for your help!  I did query the shared_preload_libraries and it was not there. I have a cluster setup and was given command to restart both resources. and for some reason now I see the pg_stat_statements.

Comment: Problem is solved:-)